# What is the difference between "?" and "= null" in PHP function parameters

Tags: php, function, parameters, php-7, nullable

I was doing some research but wasn't able to find an answer (probably beacause I did not searched it right)

Consider this piece of code:

```
public function foo(?array $optionalParam);
```

And then this one:

```
public function foo(array $optionalParam = null);
```

What differs between them? Using PHPstorm I noticed that when I use the `?`, it creates a PHPdoc and mark the variable type as `type|null`. But when I call the function without that argument, PHP screams on my face "you kidding me? where is $optionalParam". In the other side, I managed to use with no problems the `=null` option.

Sorry if this question is too simple, but i did not find any answers online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the `?` goes before the type, not after... other than this:

Using

```
public function foo(?array $optionalParam);
```

you are forced to pass something, that can be either `null` or an `array`, infact:

```
<?php
function foo(?array $optionalParam){
  echo "test";
}

foo(); // doesn't work
foo(null); // works
foo([]); // works
```

where instead using

```
public function foo(array $optionalParam = null);
```

will accept `null`, an `array`, or 0 parameters

```
<?php
function foo(array $optionalParam = null){
  echo "test";
}

foo(null); // works
foo(); // work
foo([]); // works
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a PHP 7.1 feature called [Nullable Types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)

Both of the lines you wrote are identical.

```
array ?$optionalParam : either an array or null

array $optionalParam = null : either an array or null
```

Tho using `?` you'd still need to add the parameter when calling the function.